# Nested serializers. Create method doesnt work (Contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'course')

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write a create method but got a error i cannot fix. Would you be kind look at it and give me some advises? Seems like i am doing it totally wrong. I was also fighting with keyword argument but seems liked i fixed it... It should create Courses with Contacts and Branches.

models.py

```
class Branch(models.Model):

   latitude = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   longitude = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=150)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.address

class Contact(models.Model):
   CHOICES = (
       (1,'Facebook'),
       (2,'Email'),
       (3, 'phone')
   )
   status = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)


   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.status}'

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   imgpath = models.CharField(max_length=150)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class Course(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
   related_name='category', null=True)
   logo = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='contacts', null=True)
   branches = models.ManyToManyField(Branch, related_name='branches', null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

serializers.py (Here i am trying to create new course, branches and contacts)

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Category
       fields = ('id', 'name', 'imgpath')

class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Branch
       fields = ('latitude', 'longitude', 'address')


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Contact
       fields = ('__all__')


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   category = CategorySerializer()
   contacts = ContactSerializer(many=True)
   branches = BranchSerializer(many=True)

   class Meta:
       model = Course
       fields = ['name', 'description','logo', 'category', 'contacts', 'branches']

   def create(self, validated_data):
       category_data = validated_data.pop('category')
       category = Category.objects.create(**category_data)
       contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
       branches_data = validated_data.pop('branches')
       course = Course.objects.create(**validated_data)
       for contact_data in contacts_data:
           Contact.objects.create(course=course, **contact_data)
       for branch_data in branches_data:
           Branch.objects.create(course=course, **branch_data)
       return course
```

views.py

```
class CoursesView(views.APIView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       course = Course.objects.all()
       serializer = CourseSerializer(course, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = CourseSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response({'data': 'OK'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       else:
           return Response(serializer.errors)


class CoursesDetailView(views.APIView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       doctor = Course.objects.get(id=kwargs['course_id'])
       serializer = CourseSerializer(doctor)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       course = Course.objects.get(id=kwargs['course_id'])
       course.delete()
       return Response({"data": "Delete successful!"})

class CategoryView(views.APIView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       category = Category.objects.all()
       serializer = CategorySerializer(category, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class BranchView(views.APIView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       branch = Branch.objects.all()
       serializer = CategorySerializer(branch, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = BranchSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ContactView(views.APIView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       contact = Contact.objects.all()
       serializer = CategorySerializer(contact, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Contact` model has one field: `status`.
In `Course` serializer, in `create` method you have:
`Contact.objects.create(course=course, **contact_data)`. But your `Contact` model doesn't have course field.
I suggest to start looking here.